# Nightwatch.js cannot set a string variable to an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, nightwatch.js

I am testing some JavaScript code with Nightwatch.js. I want to read a value from an input tag, increase or decrease it by 1 and then write it back to the input tag. Therefore I wrote this code:

```
.getValue('#inputConfigReading', function(result){
    val = parseInt(result.value);
    if (val % 2 == 0)
        val++;
    else
        val--;
    val = val+'';
})
.clearValue('#inputConfigReading')
.setValue('#inputConfigReading', val)
```

I checked it out. The variable `val` has the correct value after the command `val = val+'';`. But anyway when I run the code Nightwatch is writing `undefined` into the input field. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nightwatch is executing those last two steps before `val` is defined. 
Those last two steps should be inside the callback function of `.getValue`:

```
.getValue('#inputConfigReading', function(result){
    val = parseInt(result.value);
    if (val % 2 == 0)
        val++;
    else
        val--;
    val = val+'';
    browser.clearValue('#inputConfigReading')
    browser.setValue('#inputConfigReading', val)
})
```