# Nightwatch.js - Using variables for later use inside another function won't work

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I've already researched about this problem, but couldn't find a proper solution. Here's what I'm trying to do (I'm using nightwatch v0.9.8 and "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3"):

```
            var servico, dataCriado, a, selector;

            module.exports = {
             'test case': function(client) {
               client

             *** do login stuff ***

             *** go to a page and then execute this: ***

             .execute (function (){ 

    // Get all <a/> tags inside 'listaEtapasServicos':
               var estados = document.getElementsByClassName('listaEtapasServicos')[0].getElementsByTagName("a");

    // Get all divs inside with the class 'grid-cons-medium' inside 'listaEtapasServicos'
               var div = document.getElementsByClassName('listaEtapasServicos')[0].getElementsByClassName('grid-cons-medium');

    // What I'm trying to do here is to look for an element containing the text "Suspender" inside a table, save the info inside this specific table line ('Serviço' and 'Data criado') and then click on "Suspender":

           for (var i = 0; i < estados.length; i++){
             if (estados[i].innerHTML == "Suspender") {
               a = i+1;
               servico = div[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
               dataCriado = div[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;
               selector = "#div-container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.div-group-info-medium > div > div > div.listaEtapasServicos.scroll-pane-pattern.scroll-pane-medium.ps-container.ps-active-y > div:nth-child("+ a +") > div.grid-padroes-geral.grid-col-100.text-left > a";
               break;
              }
           }
          }, [])

    // Where the error happens:
         .perform(function () {
           client.click(selector);
         })

*** Test failed ***
```

**ERROR: Unable to locate element: "undefined" using: css selector**

An image of the table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuVPV.png)

The thing is that nightwatch is telling me that the variable 'selector' is undefined, even though if I write another executor before the click function with the command 'alert(selector)', the alert will return exactly the selector that I want. A problem like this was already assigned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nightwatchjs/AzRC-Sbgt4Q

But the given solution didn't work for me. Doing just '.click(selector)' also won't work. Could someone help me find a solution?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, just found a workaround here: [Nightwatch.js cannot set a string variable to an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240656/nightwatch-js-cannot-set-a-string-variable-to-an-input-field?rq=1)

Then the code will look like this:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < estados.length; i++){
     if (estados[i].innerHTML == "Suspender") {
       a = i+1;
       servico = div[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
       dataCriado = div[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;
       selector = "#div-container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.div-group-info-medium > div > div > div.listaEtapasServicos.scroll-pane-pattern.scroll-pane-medium.ps-container.ps-active-y > div:nth-child("+ a +") > div.grid-padroes-geral.grid-col-100.text-left > a";
       client.click(selector);
       break;
      }
   }
  }, [])
```

Worked. But then my problem is that I still need those variables for later use, but nightwatch won't define them. How do I make nightwatch define my variables so that they won't stay undefined? Also, why does this alert shows the selector as it was defined inside the firts executor:

```
.execute [...] (first executor)

.execute(function (){ alert (selector) })
```

... but the click inside the '.perform()' function doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

My problem was that I didn't know how the `.execute()` function actually works. It's scope is limited to the *document* object, so if I want my variables to keep the values that I want them to have, I must do it through the `callback` function.

Also, the `client` object and it's steps are all instantiated before the `.execute()` function executes, and at this time the `selector` value would still be undefined. That's why the `perform()` function is needed. The code stays like this:

```
 .execute(function () {
   var estados = document.getElementsByClassName('listaEtapasServicos')[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
   var div = document.getElementsByClassName('listaEtapasServicos')[0].getElementsByClassName("grid-cons-medium");


   for (var i = 0; i < estados.length; i++) {
     if (estados[i].innerHTML == "Suspender") {
       a = i + 1;
       servico = div[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
       dataCriado = div[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML;
       selector = "div.grid-cons-medium:nth-child("+a+") > div:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)";
       return [a, servico, dataCriado, selector];
     }
   }
 }, [], function (result) {

   a = result.value[0];
   servico = result.value[1];
   dataCriado = result.value[2];
   selector = result.value[3];

 })

 .perform(function(){
    client.waitForElementPresent(selector, 10000);
    client.click(selector);
 })
```

Now everything is working fine.